# React: how can I filter the state based on a property without mutating the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management

I have two button, one is `completedTasks` and another is `incompleteTasks`
so when user click on  `completedTasks`  I want to filter the state array based on a property. and vice versa.

but, the problem is after clicking on `completedTasks` my state array is mutated to only completedTasks filtered values.
so that, when I clicked on incompltedTasks I don't get my state back

here is my two method:

```
 const incompleteTasks = () => {
    const tasks = todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === false);
    setTodos(tasks);
  };

  const completedTasks = () => {
    const tasks = todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === true);
    setTodos(tasks);
  };
```

How to fix this so that the actual array is not modified, and just show the filtered property based on button click instead.

Comment: Don't filter them, rather add a state variable `tasksToShow: 'complete' | 'incomplete'` and then don't render the ones that you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**- First solution could be using a state for storing status of filter**

```
const [completed,setCompleted] = useState(null);  //true , false

 const incompleteTasks = () => setCompleted(false);             

 const completedTasks = () =>    setCompleted(true);
```

and use ***filteredTodos*** where you want to show

```
const filteredTodos = completed !==null ? todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === completed):todos;
```

**- Second soultion could be using a temp state:**

```
const [filteredTodos,setFilteredTodos] = useState([]);

 const incompleteTasks = () => {
    const tasks = todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === false);
    setFilteredTodos(tasks);
  };

  const completedTasks = () => {
    const tasks = todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed === true);
    setFilteredTodos(tasks);
  };
```

then show ***filteredTodos*** where you want.